# Converting non-standard file to .csv in R

Tags: r, file, csv, rstudio, file-conversion

Some of the output files I use are non-standard, space delimited formats with non-standard extensions (.out) that only have meaning to a particular program I use. For example, I might get an output file for water budgets that looks like: waterbalance.out

I can open these files in Excel by opening the file as a space delimited file and starting import on row 3.

How can I read such file types into R so that I can convert to .csv?

[image]

Comment: You can specify [`sep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) parameter to both `read.csv` and `fread` (for efficient reader).

Comment: I think R can handle non-standard extensions without a problem.  The space delimited situation is more dire.  It won't have the smarts to deal with ambiguous situations that you can easily bring to bear as you've shown.

Comment: You could try sth like `read.table(yourfilename, sep = "\t", header=TRUE, comment.char = "0")` (skip lines beginning with 0, use tab as delimitter)  or `read.table(yourfilename, sep = " ", header=TRUE, sip = 2)` (skip first two lines, use space as delimitter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a space separated file:

```
name grade percent
john 1 0.3
brian 2 0.25
joshua 5 1.1
```

You can specify a delimeter for [`read.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html):

```
> read.csv("test.ssv", sep=" ")
    name grade percent
1   john     1    0.30
2  brian     2    0.25
3 joshua     5    1.10
```

Also, `fread` from the `data.table` is able to automatically parse:

```
> library("data.table")
> fread("test.ssv")
     name grade percent
1:   john     1    0.30
2:  brian     2    0.25
3: joshua     5    1.10
```

Comment: Finally got this to work by using skip and dec arguments. Thanks!